# I am trying to change my navbar text color on scroll in each section , but its not changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var top1 = $('#profile').offset().top;
var top2 = $('#intro').offset().top;
var top3 = $('#about-me').offset().top;


$(document).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPos >= top1 && scrollPos < top2) {
    $('.link').css({"color": "#fff"});
  } else if (scrollPos >= top2 && scrollPos < top3) {
    $('.link').css({"color": "#000"});
  } else if (scrollPos >= top3) {
    $('.link').css({"color": "#fff"});
  }
});
```

I am trying to change my navbar text color on scroll in each section , but its not changing ??